# Is the FCC planning to restrict installation of custom software on radio-enabled devices?

Tags: united-states, law

Recently I came across [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Futurology/comments/3jtdg1/we_could_soon_be_have_an_unmodifiable_future_if/) regarding the fact that the FCC is planning to prevent consumers from installing custom firmware and OSes on radio/WiFi enabled devices.

Is this really what [this proposal](https://www.federalregister.gov/articles/2015/08/06/2015-18402/equipment-authorization-and-electronic-labeling-for-wireless-devices) is trying to do, or is this just a case of triggerhappy online bloggers?

Comment: It's more like prevent customers from installing custom device drivers which is a good idea in general unless you write firmware as a hobby (like me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant portion is this (emphasis mine) :

> b. Devices With Software-Based Capabilities
>
> 18. The [Software-Defined Radio] rules were intended to allow manufacturers to obtain approval for changes to the RF operating parameters of a radio resulting from software changes without the need to physically re-label a device with a new FCC ID number in the field. For a device to be certified as an SDR, in addition to demonstrating that the device complies with the applicable technical requirements, **the applicant must also demonstrate that the device contains security features to prevent the loading of software that would allow the radio to operate in violation of the Commission's rules**.

So any device containing a software defined radio would need to be prevented from having software installed on it that would allow the device to violate FCC rules.  In practice, that would mean it would have to be secured against any software that could alter the parameters of the radio set.

Any other software on the device that doesn't affect the radio set (e.g. custom router firmware) would not be affected by this proposal.

Comment: What is the source of that citation?

Comment: The source of that citation is present here-https://www.federalregister.gov/articles/2015/08/06/2015-18402/equipment-authorization-and-electronic-labeling-for-wireless-devices#h-13.

Comment: @Sklivvz - It came from the "this proposal" link in the question.